# How to deploy node js app with react to heroku

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs, heroku

I trying deploy my MERN app to heroku.

After build success on heroku doesn't see a API routes:
[image]

**Steps**: 
On localhost I run concurrently node server and client (create-react-app).
Server on port 5000 and client on port 3000.
After this I fetch from API routes /hotels Array with items and connect it to Redux store and display it.

**Properly behavior:**
[image]

**Localhost**: works fine

**Heroku**: broken (didn't connect with API)

This is my server.js file:

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();
const http = require('http');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cookieSession = require('cookie-session');
const passport = require('passport');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const keys = require('./API/config/keys');

//######### MODELS #########
require('./API/models/Users');

//######### SERVICES #########
require('./API/services/passport');

//######### MONGODB CONNECT #########
mongoose.connect(MONGO_CONNECT);

//######### ROUTES #########
const hotelsRoutes = require('./API/routes/hotels');
const countRoutes = require('./API/routes/count');
const topRoutes = require('./API/routes/top');

// Use routes
app.use('/hotels', hotelsRoutes);
app.use('/count', countRoutes);
app.use('/top', topRoutes);

app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use('/uploads', express.static('uploads'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(
  cookieSession({
      maxAge: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, // 30 days
      keys: [keys.cookieKey]
  })
);

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

require('./API/routes/authRoutes')(app);

app.use(express.static('client/build'));

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
   res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'client', 'build', 'index.html'));
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
const server = http.createServer(app);

server.listen(port);
```

**Package.json (server):**

```js
{
  "name": "root-react-hotel-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "client": "cd client && yarn start",
    "start": "node server.js",
    "start-api": "nodemon server.js",
    "dev": "concurrently \"yarn start-api\" \"yarn client\"",
    "build": "cd client && npm install && yarn build"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    //
  },
  "dependencies": {
    //
  }
}
```

**Package.json (client):**

```js
{
  "name": "client-react-hotel-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "proxy": {
    "/auth/google": {
      "target": "http://localhost:5000"
    },
    "/api/*": {
      "target": "http://localhost:5000"
    },
    "/*": {
      "target": "http://localhost:5000"
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    // Here are dependencies
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build-css": "node-sass-chokidar src/ -o src/",
    "watch-css": "npm run build-css && node-sass-chokidar src/ -o src/ --watch --recursive",
    "start-js": "react-scripts start",
    "start": "npm-run-all -p watch-css start-js",
    "build-js": "react-scripts build",
    "build": "npm-run-all build-css build-js",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "compile:sass": "node-sass src/css/styles.scss src/css/styles.css -w",
    "generate:doc": "sassdoc src/css/abstracts/_mixins.scss",
    "test": "cross-env NODE_ENV=test jest --config=jest.config.json",
    "test-coverage": "cross-env NODE_ENV=test jest --coverage --config=jest.config.json",
    "test-ci": "cross-env NODE_ENV=test jest --config=jest.config.json --coverage && cat ./coverage/lcov.info | ./node_modules/coveralls/bin/coveralls.js"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
     // Here are devDependencies
  }
}
```

Also trying with **static.json** file and Procfile:

```js
{
  "root": "client/build/",
  "setupFiles": [
    "<rootDir>/client/src/setupTests.js"
  ]
}
```

Anyone can help?

Comment: I have similar problem can anyone help https://stackoverflow.com/q/67105488/13994868

Answer (score 1):

Since your express server is serving both your react bundle and your api routes, in:

```
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
   res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'client', 'build', 'index.html'));
});
```

You need to protect your api routes in the 'app.get' when deploying to heroku (production mode). You can use a simple regex in order to serve all routes to your react bundle except '/api' (or whatever your api endpoint looks like, /API in your case above). It works running locally because you are running your api and react app on separate ports, not the same server.

Usually something like:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
      app.get(/^\/(?!api).*/, (req, res) => { // don't serve react app to api routes
        res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'client', 'build', 'index.html'));
      });
};
```