# when i deploy mern on heroku deploy problem in NODE_ENV

Tags: node.js, reactjs, deployment

every thing is ok but when we write the code in this format
only show api call in formate of json or send but not show the react template
i can't undersatnd

```
        const express = require('express');
        const app = express();
        const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
        const NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV || "devlopment"
        const path = require("path");
        var cors = require('cors')
        
        
        app.use(cors())
        app.use(express.json())
        app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
          
       app.get('/', (req, res) => {
       res.json({
              message: "Mern Deploy secces"
                })
            })
            
      app.get('/sample', (req, res) => {
        res.send("Hello Express");
            })
    
     
    
        if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
                app.use(express.static("client/build"))
            
         app.get(" * ", (req, res) => {
      res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "../client", "build", "index.html"))
                });
            
                console.log('production modde')
            }
          
 app.listen(port, () => {
        console.log('server is running on 5000')
    })
```

this is my node js file  if i write the code in this formate
only show react js not show api request

index.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
const NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV || "devlopment"
const path = require("path");
var cors = require('cors')


app.use(cors())
app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));


if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
    app.use(express.static("client/build"))

    app.get(" * ", (req, res) => {
        res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "../client", "build", "index.html"))
    });

    console.log('production modde')
}

app.get('/', (req, res) => {

    res.json({
        message: "Mern Deploy secces"
    })
})

app.get('/sample', (req, res) => {
    res.send("Hello Express");
})



app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('server is running on 5000')
})
```

This is my React js File

```
import Raact, { useEffect ,useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import axios from 'axios';

function App() {
const [show, setshow] = useState("")

useEffect(()=>{
 
  axios.get('/',)
  .then((result)=>{
    setshow(result.data.message)
  }).catch((err)=>{
    console.log(err)
  })

},[])

  return (
    <div className="App">
     <h1>Hello world</h1>
     <h1>{show}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

client package.json

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.10",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.6",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:5000/"
}
```

package.json server

```
{
  "name": "MERN-DEPLOY",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",

  "engines": {
    "node": "14.15.5",
    "npm": "7.5.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server/index.js",
    "backend": "nodemon server/index.js",
    "fontend": "npm run front --prefix client",
    "heroku-postbuild": "NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client ",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.7"
  }
}
```